# Where can I download WSS3 with Service Pack 1 (x64)?

Tags: wss-3.0, service-pack

Does anyone know if it's possible to download 64 bit WSS3 with Service Pack 1. All the downloads I have found are for SP2 but I need SP1.

My production environment runs SP1 and this can't be upgraded so my local environment must match it in order for me to restore the content database and site collection backups.

UPDATE: I should have indicated that I'm looking for the 64 bit version of WSS3. The 64 bit installer from Microsoft has SP2 packaged up in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers so far. I have managed to resolve the issue myself.

I was attempting to install WSS3 onto Server 2008. It seems that during the install process SP2 is downloaded and installed. I can only assume SP2 is required for WSS3 to work on 2008.

I'm now using a machine running Server 2003 and have managed to install WSS3 SP1.

I should have been more detailed in my question with regards to the environment I was using.

Thanks again,
Robert

Comment: You should read more carefully comments on the download page. That's all was in front of your eyes :)

Comment: Windows server 2008 does not allow you to install Sharepoint 3.0. It insists you install it with service pack then quits the installation. I'm also looking for Sharepoint 3.0 with SP1 but the only downloads available are SP2. and unlike you, I cannot switch down to server 2003 for this purpose. We are trying to restore a backup taken from version SP1, which cannot be restored into SP2!

Answer (score 3):

Here are the links:

- [Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 x86](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d51730b5-48fc-4ca2-b454-8dc2caf93951&displaylang=en)
- [Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 x64](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0A50DA0F-7C94-4814-BBFE-2B66FE4A9087)
- [SP1 for WSS 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4191a531-a2e9-45e4-b71e-5b0b17108bd2&displaylang=en) (both x64 and x86 versions are included)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I should have made it clear that I'm looking for the x64 version of WSS3.

Comment: I've updated my answer with link to x64 version of WSS3. SP1 download page includes both versions.

Comment: Thanks, the problem here though is that this x64 installer installs SP2, and once it's on, you can't uninstall it.

Comment: There is a separate page at downloads.microsoft.com for `WSS 3.0 x64 with SP2`: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=9FB41E51-CB03-4B47-B89A-396786492CBA&displaylang=en. Do you mean that `Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 x64` installer, located at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0A50DA0F-7C94-4814-BBFE-2B66FE4A9087, installs `WSS 3.0 x64 with SP2` too?!

Comment: I've managed to resolve this now, see my answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: None of these links work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you don´t want to install SP1 manually I would download WSS 3.0 and SP1 and build my own slipstreamed version. You can check this blog out even it´s for SharePoint Server 2007 with SP2 it should be done in almost the same way.

http://blog.van-huizen.com/2009/06/slipstreaming-sp2-into-sharepoint.html

Regards
Johan

Answer (score 0):

Did you try downloading WSS V3 x64 from this link? http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0A50DA0F-7C94-4814-BBFE-2B66FE4A9087 and apply SP1 http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4191a531-a2e9-45e4-b71e-5b0b17108bd2&displaylang=en after the initial install.